# DataBase First - DefaulValue for fields

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I create Model from DataBase, data table *"Clients"*, Column *"Name"* have default value 'xxx'

```
...
[Name] NVARCHAR (100) DEFAULT ('xxx') NOT NULL,
...
```

Is it possible to set a default value for the property `public string Name { get; set; }` at the generation model from the database, at default

```
Clients cl = new Clients();
```

`cl.Name` have "null" value.

**PS**: I don't want to edit any code at Model Class, because I periodically update model from the database.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: you can create a constructor in the class and within the constructor assign whatever default value you want to the property.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the entity in the entity class constructor.

In your question you say:

> **PS:** I don't want to edit any code at Model Class, because I periodically update model from the database.

That's not a problem if you use partial classes. I don't know how you update your model from the DB, but most generators create partial classes to allow you define your own partial files, so your changes are kept afeter updating the model.

The exact answer to your question would be to make a custom T4 template to generate all the stuff for you, getting the default config from the DB, but that's much harder to do.